# Android Declare a Variable

Tags: java, android, variables, global-variables

I was wondering if there is an easy way to declare a variable in android programming.  I am still teaching myself however I haven't been able to find the answer to this question.  I would like to do something like:

```
var1 = 'variable1';
var2 = 'variable2';
```

So that it can be called later in the code by its Variable.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Flush out the use-case a little more? I'm torn between if this post is looking for *instance variables* or "variable variables".

Comment: I know that it is not good programming, however this is an application that is going to be duplicated dozens and dozens of times, so I would like to have one file that declares all of the variables so every time I duplicate the project I do not have to search and replace every declaration.

Comment: you should learn java before you start developping in android

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest learning Java fundamentals first. Declaring a variable is fundamental to Java programming language (and indeed many programming languages), its not just Android specific.

You can learn Java fundamentals [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html).

Good Luck in your learning

Comment: Thank you very much for your recommendation.  This is a great resource.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
 private static final String VAR = "string constant variable";

 String var1 = "string instance variable1";
```

Android is basically Java so simple look for java references.

http://library.thinkquest.org/17862/jvar.htm

Answer (score -2):

```
int  a=10;
String b="kick";
char c;
```